# Java: Same method in two classes, however method only works in one class

Tags: java, variables, methods

## Notes

A year later reviewing this question, I'm of the opinion that this was a poor question to ask on SO, and it's a bit embarrassing. I'm unsure whether to just delete the question or to rewrite it in hopes that it may help someone if they found themselves in my shoes.

Despite reading about setters and getters I was lacking a fundamental understanding of how classes, scope, dependencies, actually worked. Asking this question at the time was of great help to me in putting the two pieces together as it was a push in the right direction.

## Edited Question

I've been studying Java by putting together my own projects. I'm currently working on a simple game, however, I've come across something that has me completely stumped. I'm sure the answer is something simple, however, I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I've got a method:

```
public void inertia () {
    y = speedY+y;
    x= speedX+x;
}
```

However it behaves differently in the two classes that I've tried it in.

When calling it in [only] one class the variable y does not seem to change [in the other class]. When calling it in [just the] another (a class responsible for animation the local variable used in that class) and the sprite falls down the screen like one would expect [however, the original class does not update]. I'd just like to know what is causing this behavior.

I included a JLabel to see the variable in the other class, and it does not change.

The desired outcome is for the the corresponding x and y values to change so that the sprite will move about the JPanel

This is the class that I'd like to call it from:

```
    public class Mochi {
        
        private float x;
        private float y;
        private float speedX = 0;
        private float speedY = 3;
        private float gravity = 3;  
        boolean mRunR = true;
        
    
        public float getSpeedY(){
                return this.speedY;
        }
        
        public float getSpeedX() {
            return this.speedX;
        }
        
        public float getX() {
                return this.x;
            }
            public float getY() {
                return this.y;
            }
       // problem method below:
        public void inertia () {
            y = speedY+y;
            x= speedX+x;
        }
        
    }
```

While testing animations, I wrote it in this class and found that it works here:

```
public class Animation {
    Image ms = new ImageIcon("mochirs.png").getImage();
    Image mws = new ImageIcon("mochiws.png").getImage();
    
    Image currentSprite;
        
    int aniTime = 1;
    int sW = 21;
    int sH = 14;
    Mochi mochi = new Mochi();
    int x = (int) mochi.getX();
    int y = (int) mochi.getY();
    int speedY = (int) mochi.getSpeedY();
    int speedX = (int) mochi.getSpeedX();
    boolean mRunR = mochi.mRunR;

    public void inertia() {
        y = speedY+y;
        x = speedX+x;
    }
    

    public void draw (Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setClip(x, y, sW, sH);
        g2.drawImage(currentSprite, x, y, sW, sH, null);
    }
    
    public void setCurrentSprite (){
        if (mRunR == true) {
            if (aniTime <= 5) {
                currentSprite = mws;
                aniTime ++;
            }else if (aniTime <= 10) {
                currentSprite = ms;
                aniTime++;
            }else  {
                aniTime = 1;
            }
        }
    }           
    
}
```

Below is that calls the method:

```
public class DogLogic extends JPanel {
    Animation animation = new Animation();
    Mochi mochi = new Mochi();
    int refreshRate = 30;


public DogLogic () {
    JPanel testPain = new JPanel();
    JLabel testLabel2= new JLabel (Integer.toString((int)mochi.getX()));
    JLabel tl3 = new JLabel (Integer.toString((int) mochi.getY()));
    JLabel tl4 = new JLabel (Integer.toString((int) mochi.getSpeedY()));
    testPain.add(testLabel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    testPain.add(tl3);
    testPain.add(tl4);
    add (testPain);         
        gameStart();

    }

    public void gameStart() {
        Thread gameThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    gameUpdate();
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000/refreshRate);
                    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("An error in gameThread has occured");
                    }
                }
            
            }
        }; 
        gameThread.start(); 
    }
    
    public void gameUpdate () {
        animation.setCurrentSprite();
        mochi.inertia(); 
        animation.intertia(); 
    }
    


        @Override
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            animation.draw(g2);
            
            }
    
}
```

## Conclusion

I was expecting one class to use variables from another class automagically because I did not understand how classes, scope, and dependencies worked in Java at the time.

If you find yourself with a similar question, research scope, dependency injection, and basic object oriented design patterns.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". You call `mochi.inertia();`, but you never seem to try to extract mochi's x or y ever again. So how can you say that it's not working? Please explain the details. What behaviors are you expecting that you're not seeing?

Comment: `Mochi mochi = new Mochi();
    int x = (int) mochi.getX();
    int y = (int) mochi.getY();`  `x` and `y` in mochi will not have any values

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yes, specifically the values for x and y do not change when calling mochi.inertia() however they do change when calling animation.inertia()

Comment: You're not showing how `speedX` and `speedY` are declared or modified - it's impossible to see how both `Mochi` and `Animation` access these

Comment: How do you know if x or y change or not if you never extract them again? Please post real code, [mcve] code, else we're just wasting our time here.

Comment: The reason I can tell x and y change is by running the program. If I use animation.intertia(); then I can see the sprite move as I would expect. When using mochi.intertia() the sprite just stays still. I added a JLabel to show the y value as well, and calling mochi.interia() doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Did you put breakpoints into the code in your IDE debugger? Can you find why the expected change is not happening? Is the code even being invoked?

Comment: Actually it would be OK to delete the question, I am just not sure if you can do that with an answer, actually, accepted, yourself. Theoretically, you could flag yourself and ask a moderator if you should delete it ... but honestly: there are so many questions around here that are really much worse. The answer is answering the question ... so just keep it in place, and move on.

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation class has two variables x and y that change when `animation.inertia()` is called.

However when you call `mochi.inertia()` in DogLogic Class, the x and y that belong to Mochi Class change. Animation Class x and y do not change at all.

So the x and y remain unchanged in Animation class when only `mochi.inertia()` is called.

Update gameUpdate in DogLogic Class :

```
 public void gameUpdate () {
     animation.setCurrentSprite();
     mochi.inertia();
     animation.updateXY(this.mochi);
 }
```

And in Animation class :

```
public void  updateXY( Mochi mochi){
    x = (int) mochi.getX();
    y = (int) mochi.getY();
}
```